# What is an efficient way to parse query result into a struct that has two fileds: a string and an array of structs using pkg sqlx?

Tags: sql, go, struct, sqlx

I have written the following query and found myself trying to find an efficient way to parse the result of it:

```sql
SELECT modes.mode_name, confs.config_name, confs.field1, confs.field2, confs.field3
    FROM modes
    JOIN confs ON modes.config_name = confs.name
    WHERE modes.mode_name = $1 ORDER BY confs.config_name ASC;
```

Foe each mode there are **multiple** corresponding configs - table `modes` has two columns forming a primary key - mode_name and config_name.

Here are the structs I have to use:

```golang
type Mode struct {
    Name string `db:"mode_name"`
    Configs   []Config
}

type Config struct {
    Name            string  `db:"name" json:"-"`
    Mode            string  `db:"mode_name" json:"mode_name,omitempty"`
    Field1          float32 `db:"field1" json:"field1,omitempty"`
    Field2          float32 `db:"field2" json:"field2,omitempty"`
    Field3          float32 `db:"field3" json:"field3,omitempty"`
}
```

I expect to find a way to populate Mode struct with the data from the query above:

1. Name from mode_name
2. Then parse each corresponding config into Config struct and add them to []Configs into the Configs field

I have studied the docs for pkg sqlx, picked and tried several options that looked promising:

- [sqlx.QueryxContext](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx@v1.2.0?utm_source=gopls#DB.QueryxContext) alongside attempting to iterate over Rows with [StructScan](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx@v1.2.0?utm_source=gopls#Rows.StructScan)
- [sqlx.NamedExec](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx@v1.2.0?utm_source=gopls#DB.NamedExecContext) - parsing directly into the struct (which fails yet again as mine has an embedded struct inside).

Both of them failed and I am beginning to think there might be no elegant way to solve the task in these circumstances with the aforementioned tools.

Comment: In this case, you don't need to select and scan the `mode_name`, you already have it since that's what you're passing to the query as `$1`. So just scan the remaining config fields and set the mode name directly with a plain assignment.

Comment: Oh, this is brilliant and a bit embarrassing =) Thank you!